# Rails 4 updating Object content with out saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am preparing the Object variables before i start saving the details into the Database.

I have 3 objects i need to save `order`, `order_event`, `message`

I have instanciated the object order_event and want to update the order parameters before i save to the database

```
@order_event = OrderEvent.new(order_event_params)
    @order_event.update_attributes(event_date: @event.event_date)
```

But Rails is trying to save it to the Database and throwing the following error

```
Mysql2::Error: Field 'order_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `order_events` (`created_at`, `event_date`, `event_id`, `no_of_ppl`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-04-17 10:20:11', '2015-01-22 00:00:00', 2, 1, '2015-04-17 10:20:11')
```

My Model

```
--- !ruby/object:OrderEvent
attributes:
  id: 
  order_id: 
  event_id: 2
  no_of_ppl: 3
  event_date: 
  cost: 
  total_cost: 
  status: 
  created_at: 
  updated_at:
```

I want to update **event_date, cost, total_cost** etc before saving.

Comment: May be you want to use `assign_attributes` ? It does not persist object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `assign_attributes` for assigning params instead of `update_attributes`  (it persists them)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value to your params hash and then update:

```
@order_event = OrderEvent.find(params[:id])
params[:order_event][:event_date] = @event.event_date
if @order_event.update_attributes(order_event_params)
    ...
```